# simple fade in and out of images with arrow left and right

Tags: jquery

The current script works fine, but I need to use the arrow left to go the previous image and arrow right to go to the next one.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $images;
        var goNext = function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $next = $this.next('img').length > 0 ? $this.next('img') : $this.siblings('img').eq(0);
            $this.hide();
            $next.show();
            return false;
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $images = $('.images img');
            $images.eq(0).siblings().hide();
            $images.on('click', goNext);
        });
    </script>
```

How can I use the following to control the images sliding in and out?

```
        $("body").keydown(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
          }
        });
```

If I wanted to use the left arrow to go back what would I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go next when `right` is pressed, trigger the `click` event on the images -

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        $('.images img:visible').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfVN6/19/).

I believe now you can tweak it for both way navigation.

---

Full Code. Markup -

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" width="1920" alt="1">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" width="1920" alt="2">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" width="1920" alt="3">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" width="1920"  alt="4">
    <img src="images/5.jpg" width="1920"  alt="5">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" width="1920" alt="6">
    <img src="images/7.jpg" width="1920" alt="7">
    <img src="images/8.jpg" width="1920" alt="8">
    <img src="images/9.jpg" width="1920" alt="9">
    <img src="images/10.jpg" width="1920" alt="10">
</div>
```

JavaScript -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $images;
    var goNext = function (event, direction) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $next;

        if (direction == 'left') {    
            $next = $this.prev('img').length > 0 ? 
                    $this.prev('img') : 
                    $this.siblings('img:last');
        }
        else {
            $next = $this.next('img').length > 0 ? 
                    $this.next('img') : 
                    $this.siblings('img:first');
        }

        $this.hide();
        $next.show();

        return false;
    };

    $images = $('.images img');
    $images.eq(0)
        .siblings()
        .hide();
    $images.on('click', goNext);

    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
            $('.images img:visible').trigger('click', 'right');
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
            $('.images img:visible').trigger('click', 'left');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: strange thing to go next by pressing `left`

Comment: well left would go to the previous image and right to the next one

Comment: @Alex uncomment `click` binding, or else there's nothing to trigger. I think that's not the best way to handle this.

Comment: If I wanted to use the left arrow to go back what would I need to add in the code?

Comment: With `$('.images img')`, you are clicking all the images at once which will invoke the function n number of times which will in effect, will be like always clicking the last `img`!

Comment: thanks but how can edit the code to use both arrows to fade images in and out?

Comment: @Mathew: No, this code is only triggering the `click` event for the visible image. I used the first code snippet only for example. Full code doesn't trigger the click event for all the images.